# How do I write unit test against the AuthSession object?

Tags: unit-test, session

I have some code which uses the [AuthSession](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm) to check if a user is logged in and set some auto assignment rules based on that. However, I am not sure how to cover this in my unit test. Is there a way to create the AuthSession or simulate user login in my tests? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AuthSession is a read only object and hence check if it is available in test class automatically like other objects .If not then you can just use Test.isRunningTest() to avoid the execution during test run .

I am not sure why you are not using [Userinfo.getsessionId()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) as that seems to be available in the Test class .

Also to run as specific user you can use [System.RunAs(User)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm?search_text=RunAs) method .

Comment: AuthSession object support's delete operations. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm

Answer (score 1):

For objects that are read only and require testing you can change your framework a bit:

1. Create a class that the object can be deserialized into or constructed
2. Use that class in your code instead of the object

If you do the above then you can mock your test data at will.

For example:

**Mock Account Class**

```
public class myMockAccount{
     public String name {get;set;}

     public myMockAccount(Account a){
         name = a.name;
     }
}
```

**Example code using this instead of account**

```
public static void exampleCode(){

     Account a = [Select ID, Name From Account];
     myMockAccount mockAccount = New myMockAccount(a);

     system.debug(mockAccount.name); //Instead of using Account

}
```

It all depends on how important your test methods are.